# Keep only records in table 1 that correspond to unique value in table 2

Tags: datatables, sas, enterprise-guide

I'm working the current version of SAS Enterprise Guide.

I have data in two tables; Table 1 contains a list of account numbers, and Table 2 contains individual records for each account number and each month. The account number is a unique value in Table 1, but repeats in Table 2 depending on how many months the account is active.  Table 2 also contains more unique account numbers than Table 1, so i need to create a query that keeps only the records in Table 2 for which the account numbers appear in Table 1.

Table 1 is a list of unique account numbers that I want to perform further analysis on.  I want to use that list to filter out unwanted account numbers from the much larger list in Table 2.

Table 1 is a list of unique account numbers that I want to perform further analysis on.  I want to use that list to filter out unwanted account numbers from the much larger list in Table 2.

Comment: What did you try? Were there any errors?

Comment: The EG UI facilitates such data operations.  Did you try a simple join on the account number? The relationship of one to two is known as any of these -- 1:many, parent:child, master:detail and is commonly enforced by a primary key constraint in the master table and a foreign key constraint in the detail table.  A robust data store usually does not have detail records for which there is no master record.

Comment: @Richard I've tried several different join types and filters and mostly end up with either all of the records from Table 2, or blank records.  The problem is that I really have no idea how the query wizard works in EG, and everything I've seen on google just gives a very simple and cursory explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in different ways. I would be using proc sql :into clause to create macro variable for list of account numbers from Table1:

```
proc sql;
select distinct account_no into: tab1_act_list separated by "," from table1;
quit;

data table2_temp;
 set table2;
 if account_no in(&tab1_act_list) then delete; /*Or whatever you want to do with these obs*/
run;
```

Alternatively, you can use Merge, sql-joins.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table Rst as 
  select * from Tab2
  where Account in (
    select distinct Account from Tab1
  )
 ;
quit;
```

If variable names are the same for both Tab1 and Tab2 then `intersect` statment will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, your table 2 contains information from multiple dates;
Therefore if you need the latest data for each account number from table 1, you need to:

1. Run a Query Builder from table 2, with MAX of each date, e.g. [query builder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miLVQ.png)
2. Then, just join 2 tables by account number using INNER join -- it keeps only that records, which appear on both of the tables